# SQL Server 2012 - How to map JSON object to a table

Tags: sql-server, json, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have created a SQL Server 2012 stored procedure that calls a function which returns a JSON object and stores it in a declared variable called `@stormOutages`.

I'd like to be able to map the JSON object to 3 tables in the database. Is there a built-in function that could help me do this or do I have to parse the JSON object manually?

Scroll down to see the SP and the JSON object.

The stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertStormOutages
--@StormOutage NVARCHAR(MAX),
--@url NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @stormOutages NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        @stormOutages = dbo.GetStormOutages('https://dummywebservice.com/values')

    SELECT 
        @stormOutages AS ReturnedJSON
END
```

JSON:

> {"lastupdated":"08/26/2015 05:00 PM","counties":{"alachua":{"name":"Alachua","numberofoutages":222,"numberofrestored":222,"numberofaffected":222,"numberofaccounts":1300}},"statewide":{"name":"Statewide","numberofoutages":1340237,"numberofrestored":388972,"numberofaffected":1728987,"numberofaccounts":4760460}}

Comment: SQL Server 2012 doesn't have any native support for JSON - the upcoming SQL Server **2016** will have native JSON support for both creating JSON from relational data, as well as parsing JSON into relational pieces

Comment: @marc_s I am able to manipulate the JSON object before it is actually sent to the stored procedure. Do you think I can put it in XML format and then map it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the JSON object was being retrieved from a web service through a DLL I created using CLR(VS .NET). So I converted the JSON into XML in .NET using C# and then built the assembly file and exported it into SQL Server 2012. From there I made a Stored Procedure, parsed through the xml data and inserted the values I needed into a respective table.